# Difficulties with dynamic resize of widget and configuring two instances of widget

Tags: android, glance-appwidget

I am trying to build dynamic resizing of a widget of a Calendar (to show 1 month or 2 months depending on available space).

I have added these preview layouts in AppWidgetProvider.

```
    private fun updatePreviewLayout(
        appWidgetIds: IntArray,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        context: Context
    ) {
        appWidgetIds.forEach { appWidgetId ->
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, supportedSizes) {
                calendarLog("onUpdate: layout size: $it")
                val layoutId = when (it) {
                    supportedSizes[0] -> R.layout.calendar_widget_small_layout
                    supportedSizes[1] -> R.layout.calendar_widget_two_months_layout
                    else -> R.layout.calendar_widget_small_layout
                }
                RemoteViews(context.packageName, layoutId)
            }
        }
    }
```

So, couple of questions:

1. So, with this setup, I see both my preview layouts correctly, but when I try to instantiate second widget, it literally just renders preview layout and not the actual widget.
2. If dynamically resizing, do we even need to show a pre-canned preview for second widget or just have one widget and let Glance render the LIVE two month view?

Comment: I am a bit confused since this is for traditional Widget without Glance but your second question is around Glance. Glance handles this differently. In any case preview is always needed and set in the widget metadata. The preview will be shown from the moment it's placed till the first update is received. Are you updating the widget correctly? When not using glance make sure to update properly https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets#handle-events

Comment: Thanks @Marcel. Actually I am doing a Glance widget. There is so much conflicting documentation. Finally I was able to resolve this issue.

I relied on Google's Weather App Demo (https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples).

So, I saw that they had two broadcast receivers and I had mimicked them. So, the fix was to remove the second receiver, so now I only see one instance of app widget and resize works from Glance. Impressed with Glance. I hope it goes into beta and release soon.